# Adfruit Braincraft Hat TFT Configuration on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: python, raspberry-pi4, adafruit

I am new to the world of Raspberry Pi and all that it could be done with one of these microcomputers. Recently I got one Raspbeery Pi 4 to be exact, along with it I got one of Adafruit's Braincraft Hats which has a small TFT display with 240x240 resolution.

It seems that to make work the the whole Braincraft Hat including its TFT display you need to run a  legacy version of the Raspberry Pi OS so I did re-installed the OS from a legacy option provided by Raspberry Pi with a kernel version that is somewhere around the 5.10 version.

When I start trying to configure all the services of the Braincraft Hat everything seems to be working ok until I come up to the TFT display configuration none of the fixes I had found including one which theorically addresses the problem in Gighub seems to work.

I would like to know if there is any one who has encounter the same troubleshooting and has come up with a solution to make the Adafruit Braincraft Hat work over a 5.10.* Raspberry Pi OS Kernel.

I had tried to run a particular script that supposed to fix all the driver's problems over a 5.10 kernel and I was expecting it to work and let me use the TFT display monitor on the Braincraft Hat, that would allow this small monitor to get everything that is going on from the terminal of the Raspberry Pi. Here are some partial readings from the terminal once the script finishes runing with one error and one warning.

```
***THIS IS A RED FLAG ERROR***
PITFT /boot/overlays/drm-minipitft13.dtbo: Warning (unit_address_vs_reg): /fragment@0/__overlay__/spidev@0: node has a unit name, but no reg property
/boot/overlays/drm-minipitft13.dtbo: Warning (unit_address_vs_reg): /fragment@0/__overlay__/spidev@1: node has a unit name, but no reg property
############# UPGRADING KERNEL ###############
Updating packages...
Upgrading packages...
PITFT Reading package lists...
PITFT 
PITFT Building dependency tree...
PITFT Reading state information...
PITFT 
PITFT Calculating upgrade...
PITFT 
PITFT 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Pinning kernel to version 5.4
PITFT Failed to pin all kernel files! ***THIS IS A YELLOW WARNING***
```

Thank you I sure will appreciate any help.